# Gradient background color in CSS

Tags: css, gradient

I am developing a website that has a background with two slightly different colors, one that fades into the other.  #87a0b4 to #6a86a0

http://overactiverexburg.com/Sage/index.php

I have two problems,

first, it's not working on IE or Firefox

second, I want the gradient or fade to start later, more like 80% the way down the page

```
#grad {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#87a0b4, #6a86a0); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#87a0b4, #6a86a0)); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#87a0b4, #6a86a0)); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    background: linear-gradient(#87a0b4, #6a86a0)); /* Standard syntax */
}
```

Comment: Please post your relevant code here

Comment: I just read that IE does support gradients

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first problem is extremely simple to fix. You have two ) at the end of all the gradients except the webkit gradient. That is the reason it only worked in Chrome. Also, it seems both of your colors are very simpler, it is hard to tell if there is a gradient at all.

## **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ImagineStudios/yZe8M/)**

CSS:

```
#grad {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#87a0b4, #6a86a0); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#87a0b4, #6a86a0); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#87a0b4, #6a86a0); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    background: linear-gradient(#87a0b4, #6a86a0); /* Standard syntax */
}
```

Your second question can be fixed by using a color stop to place where you want the gradient colors to meet:

```
#grad {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(red 80%, yellow); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(red 80%, yellow); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(red 80%, yellow); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    background:linear-gradient(red 80%, yellow );/* Standard syntax */
}
```

## **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ImagineStudios/yZe8M/1/)**

Here is some good articles about gradients:
http://css-tricks.com/css3-gradients/
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-understanding-css3-gradients--net-10451
http://www.creativebloq.com/master-css-gradients-8114262

Comment: @user906357 Not really. It is just a small typo that is easy to miss. glad I could help!

Answer (score -1):

```css
.box {
  position: relative;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  z-index: 1; 
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom,pink, grey);
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
 
</head>
 
<body>
  <div1>
 
    <div class="box"></div>
 
  </div1>
 
 
</body>
 
</html>
```